# 編集中のDataGridViewのあるFormが閉じることができない

Tags: vb.net

Microsoft Visual Basic 2015で以下のソースがうまく行きません、どこか間違い（足りない）がありますか。

```
Private Sub DataGridView_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView.Leave
    Dim dgv As DataGridView = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)

    If dgv.IsCurrentCellInEditMode Then
        dgv.CurrentCell = Nothing
    End If

    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

補足：
編集状態（F2押下）でなければ、フォーカスがDataGridViewから離れると、Formが閉じられます。

Comment: 「うまく行きません」とのことですが、期待する動作と実際の結果、どのように異なっているのかを説明してください。

Comment: sayuri さん
返信ありがとうございます。

説明不足ですいません。
編集かどうかに関らず、Formが閉じられることが期待しています。
現状は編集中じゃない方だけ正しく動けます。

以上、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: なぜか分りませんが、FormClosingイベントのe.CancelがTrueとなってしまいました。

Answer (score 0):

完璧な解決方法まだ見つかってませんが、以下の方法で行けそうです。

```
Private Sub Me_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    If ForceToCloseForm Then
        e.Cancel = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView.Leave
    Dim dgv As DataGridView = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)

    If dgv.IsCurrentCellInEditMode Then
        dgv.CurrentCell = Nothing
        ForceToCloseForm = True
    End If

    Me.Close()
End Sub
```